# show loading picture before delete by jquery

Tags: php, jquery, git

i have this code for delete record from database :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".delete_class").click(function(){
   var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'admin.php?page=branches-and-city/branches-and-city.php&action=deletepicdone',
      data:'delete_id='+del_id,
      success:function(data) {
        if(data) {   
        $("#pic"+del_id).fadeOut(500,function(){
                    $("#pic"+del_id).remove();  
                    });
        alert ("تم مسح الصورة.");
        } else { alert("لم يتم مسح الصورة الرجاء المحاولة فيما بعد."); }
      }
   });
 });
});
```

so i need when browser send data to url that is " `admin.php?page=branches-and-city/branches-and-city.php&action=deletepicdone` ", show me the picture or something that call me the delete is process.

how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div  showing the "processing picture"

```
   <div class="loading" style="display:none">Processing . . .</div>


  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".delete_class").click(function(){
  $('.loading').show();//show the div
  var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'admin.php?page=branches-and-city/branches-and-city.php&action=deletepicdone',
  data:'delete_id='+del_id,
  success:function(data) {
    $('.loading').hide();//hide div after success
    if(data) {   
    $("#pic"+del_id).fadeOut(500,function(){
                $("#pic"+del_id).remove();  
                });
    alert ("تم مسح الصورة.");
    } else { alert("لم يتم مسح الصورة الرجاء المحاولة فيما بعد."); }
  }
  });
 });
 });
```

Comment: thank you , how can i show black background for all page when the `.loading` div is show.

Comment: in your css add .loading { background: #000;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:100;top:0;left:0;position:absolute; }

Answer (score 0):

Add `image.show()` before ajax call, and `image.hide()` in success function

Answer (score 0):

Include an hidden indicator . Then after

```
   var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

change the display attribute of the indicator to make it visible, and inside the sucess function of the ajax call, change again the display attribute of the indicator to hidden

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the `del_id` variable doesn't extend into the `success` function. Try `$(this).fadeOut(...)` instead.